# How can I refresh the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, refresh

I want to do a dynamic form in Swing. When I call firstly the `dataShow` method, it creates the GUI. But when I call it again, it keeps the old panel and display the new at the background.

And when I try to remove the current panel, and then add the new. The GUI became empty

A `Thread` listen to events (int id in that case).

here is my code to display the dynamic form :

```
 public void showData(int id) throws DAOException, ClassNotFoundException{

        FormDAOImpl form = new FormDAOImpl();
        String b = form.importTagPoint(id);
        //if(compteur%2 == 0) {System.out.println("Compteur : " +compteur); scrollPane.remove(panel); 
        //frame.getContentPane().remove(scrollPane);
        //}
        panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

        if(b == null) b = "";
        String[] bits = b.split("\\,");
        String delims = "[=]";
        while(i<bits.length){
            textField = new JTextField();
            String[] bitsS = bits[i].split(delims);
            textField.setText(bitsS[1]);

            JLabel label = new JLabel(bitsS[0]+ " :    ");
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(textField, "span, grow, alignx center, flowx");
            i++;
        }

        JButton annuler = new JButton("Annuler");
        JButton enregistrer = new JButton("Enregistrer");

        panel.add(annuler);
        panel.add(enregistrer);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.revalidate();
        scrollPane.repaint();

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        //frame.repaint();
        frame.invalidate();
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 800));

        compteur++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, try calling `frame.getContentPane().removeAll()` to remove anything that was previously added to it.  Obviously do this before you add anything new to it.

Second, try and devise a solution where you don't need to do this, but maintain a single view which can be updated via setters and getters if possible.

If you are literally changing views (show the user something complete different), consider using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) instead

Comment: +1 for "CardLayout or JTabbedPane" I think it'll be better choice

Comment: As I said, I try frame.getContentPane().removeAll() before add anything new but the gui become empty after le 2nd call.

Comment: Alright, I will try CardLayout and JTabbedPane. Thank you

Comment: @user3645115 There was no mention of `frame.getContentPane().removeAll()` in your original post...